# Avoid matching discriminated union when type is known

Tags: f#

I have some hardware connected to my PC. The hardware consists of two components each with the ability to read some stuff from its surroundings (e.g. temperature).

I communicate with the hardware using a protocol and I have implemented that protocol in F# and I have this (simplified) model:

I can query the hardware about values/readouts of the each of the sub components and each sub component has different values I can query with different types.

```
type ChannelAResponse =
    | Data1 of float
    | Data2 of string

type ChannelBResponse =
    | Data1 of int
    | Data2 of string

type Response =
    | ChannelA of ChannelAResponse
    | ChannelB of ChannelBResponse

type ResponseMessage =
    { Id : int
      Response : Response }

// The `msg` is actually constructed from the data sent from the hardware
// where this `msg` is just an example.
let response = Response.ChannelB <| ChannelBResponse.Data2 "Everything ok"
let msg = {Id=10; Response=response}
```

A this point I know - from the protocol - that `response` is `Response.ChannelB` and it's data is `ChannelBResponse.Data2`.
Even though I know this, I still have to do something like following to get the actual string value out

```
let data = match msg.Response with
| Response.ChannelB x ->
    match x with
    | ChannelBResponse.Data2 y -> y
```

which is sort of OK because the protocol guarantees that match doesn't fail, but it's cumbersome to write this for all possible combinations.

Is there an easier way to "cast" the `msg.Response` into a string in this case?

Comment: You don't need nested `match`es for this. You can just write `| Response.ChannelB (ChannelBResponse.Data2 y) -> y`

Comment: At the point where the type of response becomes known, you should stop carrying the full response forward and start carrying just the relevant case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to your incomplete pattern match, but shorter

```
let (ChannelB(Data2 data)) = msg.Response
// val data : string = "Everything ok"

warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value 'ChannelA (_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).
```